# running a docker loop device on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to aws and am having some issues with getting my mobile app back running again. Forgive me if this question seems vague.

For a school project we created a mobile app on aws and deployed using docker containers (another student managed these tasks). When trying to get my own key pair to ssh into my ec2 instance i detached the volume associated with my instance and reattached it after getting my own key pair. Now i can ssh into my instance but my front end cant talk to my web server.

So my question is, do i create a new application on elastic beanstalk to deploy my app? Even though when i run lsblk is shows a have a docker loop device and when i run docker images i see several that match the name of my application?  or do i somehow get the container running again, docker run doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

No need, just upload a new update into Elastic Beanstalk. AWS will handle the rest.

FYI, Elastic Beanstalk - Single Docker Container update process (simple under the hood):

1. You upload the update into AWS.
2. AWS will put it on your S3.
3. Inside your EC2, there is an Elastic Beanstalk agent. It will check for a new update.
4. If there is an update, the agent will download the update file and extract it.
5. The agent will build a new Docker image.
6. If the build is success, it will generate a new config to tell Nginx (web proxy) the new web server container.
7. Nginx will be reloaded.
8. Your old docker container will be destroyed.

Don't change anything inside EC2 of Elastic Beanstalk, except you know what you do. Elastic Beanstalk is design for automate deployment and scaling. So, if you change something in your EC2 manually, it might be lost. Of course, you can modified your EC2 instance, but you need to automate it using `.ebextensions` or take an image.

Comment: thanks so much, this is extremely helpful. i was curious about deploying/uploading the docker container. We do automated builds via jenkins, which pushed a docker image to a docker hub. Or project documentation suggests some sort of automation from pushing to the hub to updating on aws but I'm not seeing how this works. I have my artifact on my machine but i don't think this is what i am supposed to upload (its a .jar not a .war, I'm developing via scala on intellij not eclipse). My question is, a) how do i complete step 1 of you above answer and b) is jenkins just for producing a jar file?

Comment: Have you create an Single Docker Container environment in Elastic Beanstalk? If you already have one, just upload your Dockerfile (scala) + your *.jar into Elastic Beanstalk Web Console.

Comment: If you want to automate your deployment using Jenkins, you can take look into [this](http://blog.adaofeliz.com/2014/12/13/continuous-delivery-jenkins-and-elastic-beanstalk/) post. I suggest you to deploy it manually first into Elastic Beanstalk before you automate it using Jenkins.